# How to fix “ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead” in sklearn/python?

Tags: python

i got this eror messsages on jupytet notebook python

> ---
>
> ```
> ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
> <ipython-input-47-24ba7430f88f> in <module>
> ----> 1 y_pred = nbtrain.predict(x_test)
>       2 y_pred
>
> ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\naive_bayes.py in predict(self, X)
>      63             Predicted target values for X
>      64         """
> ---> 65         jll = self._joint_log_likelihood(X)
>      66         return self.classes_[np.argmax(jll, axis=1)]
>      67 
>
> ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\naive_bayes.py in _joint_log_likelihood(self, X)
>     428         check_is_fitted(self, "classes_")
>     429 
> --> 430         X = check_array(X)
>     431         joint_log_likelihood = []
>     432         for i in range(np.size(self.classes_)):
>
> ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py in check_array(array, accept_sparse, accept_large_sparse, dtype, order,
> ```
>
> copy, force_all_finite, ensure_2d, allow_nd, ensure_min_samples,
>   ensure_min_features, warn_on_dtype, estimator)
>           519                     "Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if "
>           520                     "your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) "
>       --> 521                     "if it contains a single sample.".format(array))
>           522 
>           523         # in the future np.flexible dtypes will be handled like object dtypes
>
> > ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead: array=[3 3 3 2]. Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data
> >     has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single
> >     sample.

this is my code :

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

x_train, x_test, y_train, x_test = train_test_split(x,y, test_size = 0.34, random_state=123)

modelnb=GaussianNB()

nbtrain=modelnb.fit(x_train,y_train)

y_pred = nbtrain.predict(x_test)
y_pred
```

Comment: Try following the suggestion maybe? Your data is a single dimensional array, sklearn is asking for a 2 dimensional array. The error message gave you two ways to reshape your 1D array into a 2D array depending on your use case.

Answer (score 2):

Check your x_test. If it has only 1 sample, then use

```
x_test.reshape(1, -1)
```

just before you call `predict()`.

If however, your code has only 1 feature, then use

```
x_test.reshape(-1, 1)
```

again, just before you call `predict()`.